# warning Lockfile has incorrect entry for "prismjs@1.24.0". Ignoring it

Tags: github, package.json, prismjs, dependabot, yarn-lock.json

I have inherited an issue with prismjs whereby I have to remove/reinstall it every time I add/upgrade another package.

I have a gocd pipeline validation that fails every time I try to use dependabot to address security vulnerabilities on my repo.

Goes something like this....

dependabot generates pull request

validation fails with error "warning Lockfile has incorrect entry for "prismjs@1.24.0". Ignoring it"

Pull down master branch > upgrade package manually > remove/install prismjs@1.24.0

Generate new PR > validation succeeds and everything works fine.

Merge with master

rinse and repeat.

What I am seeing is that I have 2 entries in my yarn.lock for prismjs and removing it only removes the 1.24.0 entry AND, if I leave 1.24.0 removed the validation still fails because it cant find prismjs 1.24.0.

prismjs@1.24.0:
version "1.24.0"
resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/prismjs/-/prismjs-1.24.0.tgz#0409c30068a6c52c89ef7f1089b3ca4de56be2ac"
integrity sha512-SqV5GRsNqnzCL8k5dfAjCNhUrF3pR0A9lTDSCUZeh/LIshheXJEaP0hwLz2t4XHivd2J/v2HR+gRnigzeKe3cQ==

prismjs@^1.23.0, prismjs@^1.8.4, prismjs@~1.17.0:
version "1.26.0"
resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/prismjs/-/prismjs-1.26.0.tgz#16881b594828bb6b45296083a8cbab46b0accd47"
integrity sha512-HUoH9C5Z3jKkl3UunCyiD5jwk0+Hz0fIgQ2nbwU2Oo/ceuTAQAg+pPVnfdt2TJWRVLcxKh9iuoYDUSc8clb5UQ==

package.json:
"dependencies": {
"comma-separated-tokens": "^1.0.0",
"elliptic": "^6.0.0",
"handlebars": "^4.1.2",
"http-proxy": "^1.17.0",
"https-proxy-agent": "^2.2.1",
"immer": "9.0.6",
"ini": "^1.3.5",
"lodash": "^4.5.1",
"markdown-to-jsx": "^6.9.1",
"merge-deep": "^3.0.2",
"nested-object-assign": "1.0.4",
"parse-headers": "^2.0.0",
"prismjs": "1.24.0",
"space-separated-tokens": "^1.0.0",
"ssri": "^6.0.1",
"tar": "4.4.19",
"tree-kill": "^1.1.0",
"ua-parser-js": "^0.7.9",
"url-parse": "^1.4.3",
"websocket-extensions": ">=0.1.1",
"y18n": "^4.0.0",
"yargs-parser": "^13.1.1"
},
"resolutions": {
"prismjs": "^1.23.0",
"property-expr": "^2.0.3"

I'm relatively new to how this versioning works and like I say I inherited this issue so I don't really have a history besides what I can see in github.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

By Running `yarn why prismjs` that will explain which packages other than your project depend on `prismjs`.

I'm not sure if you've other packages that depend on `prismjs` to explain these other entries. It seems that some of the dependencies are hoisted to me. If you've a monorepo setup or work with nested packages, that could explain it.

Maybe helpful info as well, according to [Yarn docs](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/#toc-tips-tricks)

> You will receive a warning if your resolution version or range is not compatible with the original version range.

> Nested packages may not work properly.